# How can we use Birnbaum importance measure for complicated systems in reliability?

Tags: reliability

Birnbaum importance measure is used when we are provided the survival probabilities of all the components in a coherent system. It is the rate of increase in the system reliability with respect to the increase in component reliability. I studied some application of this method in series and parallel systems , but couldn't find any use of this method in complicated problems...
Do we need any decomposition methods like tie-set or cut-set for these problems?
for example if we have this system:
[a complicated system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gosoh.jpg)

Comment: Remind us what the "birnbum importance measure" is, please.

Comment: It is used when we are provided the survival probabilities of all the components in a coherent system. It is the rate of increase in the system reliability with respect to the increase in component reliability.

Comment: Edit your question to say so, then.